# Access array variable in session CodeIgniter

Tags: php, codeigniter, session

I have a session variable for a shopping cart like this

```
Array
(
    [session_id] => fe70285240b5525f48c5ab2e3459c017
    [ip_address] => ::1
    [user_agent] => Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 6.1; rv:30.0) Gecko/20100101 Firefox/30.0
    [last_activity] => 1404403254
    [user_data] => 
    [cart_contents] => Array
        (
            [66eeaa0e65f3bf68db770c4c1b29891e] => Array
                (
                    [rowid] => 66eeaa0e65f3bf68db770c4c1b29891e
                    [id] => SP004
                    [qty] => 10
                    [price] => 1500
                    [name] => Vegi Pizza Big
                    [image] => pizza-buena.jpg
                    [subtotal] => 15000
                )

            [total_items] => 10
            [cart_total] => 15000
        )

)
```

Can some one please help me to access the `[cart_total]` variable in this session . I have tried some thing like this

```
echo $this->session->all_userdata($session_data['cart_total']);
```

but it gives me an error **Undefined index: cart_total**

I also tried with `foreach`

```
  foreach ($session_data as $row)
        {
            $info = array(
                'user_name' => $row['user_name'],
                'cart_total'   => $row['cart_total'],
                'session_id' => $row['session_id']
            );
        }
```

but it only gives session_id not **user_name** and the **cart_total**

Comment: You mean `$session_data['cart_contents']['cart_total']` ?

Comment: yes that is what I meant ..

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Shouldn't you just be able to do this? assuming $session_data is all the session data.

```
   $session_data['cart_contents']['cart_total'];
```

I would maybe use a tertiary like this

```
$total = ( isset(  $session_data['cart_contents']['cart_total'] ) ) ?  $session_data['cart_contents']['cart_total'] : 0;
```

if that works, though just in case there is no total to prevent the error.

Answer (score 0):

I think you have to use like below

> echo
>   $this->session->all_userdata($session_data['cart_contents']['cart_total']);